# How to authenticate HashiCorp Vault without certificate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hashicorp-vault

Below is my code:

```
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(
    url='https://vault-abc.net',token='s.d0AGS4FE3o6UxUpVTQ0h0RRd',verify='False'
)

print(client.is_authenticated())
```

**ERROR in output:**

> in cert_verify
> raise IOError("Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, " OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate
> bundle, invalid path: False

I got only token and URL to login on console from client no certificates shared! In other java applications code without using any certificate authentication working but in python code under hvac module or CURL or vault CLI expecting certificates to be passed. Any way I can handle this and fix above error?

Do we have any certificate check skip option?

Agenda is authenticate and do fetch vault secrets using python program, without any certificates need  to fetch just with Token & vault URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable certificate checks, but for something like Vault that's generally a bad idea (disabling security checks on a security service).

In any case, your problem is simple: You are passing `'False'` (a string) where you should be passing `False` (a boolean) as the `verify` argument.

Passing a string causes the library to look for a certificate at that path; since there is no certificate at the path `'False'`, you get the error that you are seeing.